# swipe to another activity(Intent doesnt work)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, swipe

Main.java

```
public class Main extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    View v = findViewById(R.id.main);
    v.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this) {
        public void onSwipeTop() {
            Toast.makeText(Main.this, "top", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        public void onSwipeRight() {
            Intent i = new Intent(Main.this, Rev.class);
            startActivity(i);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.inl, R.anim.outl);
        }
        public void onSwipeLeft() {
            Toast.makeText(Main.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        public void onSwipeBottom() {
            Toast.makeText(Main.this, "bottom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });

};
```

OnSwipeTouchListener.java

```
public abstract class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

protected final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

public OnSwipeTouchListener (Context ctx){
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
}

private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                }
                result = true;
            } 
            else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        onSwipeBottom();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeTop();
                    }
                }
                result = true;

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public void onSwipeRight() {

}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
}

public void onSwipeTop() {
}

public void onSwipeBottom() {
}
```

;

main.xml

```
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="fill"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.joker.charsoo.Main"
android:background="@drawable/glass"
android:id="@+id/main" >
```

I have a weired problem! When i swipe to right nothing happens but Im getting toast for another directions...
a little help please.

Thank you.

Comment: You'd better post logcat output instead of that `blah`

Comment: also swiping between these screens sounds more like you should be using fragments not activities